# update Gallery/ListView item views from a timer

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, gallery, adapter

I want to update the UI from a timer. That's not a problem at all but when it comes to Gallery/ListViews it gets difficult. I have a Gallery with custom BaseAdapter. I need a counter for every (gallery) item (every item counts different depending on the items data). That counter should run outside of the main thread. In addition I don't want to run 10 threads for 10 items of the gallery when just one item is visible. It's not a problem to define a Handler and start a thread (the counting) in the adapters getView()-method when a item/view gets visible. I can think of something like the following code:

`public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {`

```
    static class ViewHolder {
         //...
         public Handler myHandler;
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //...
            // getView() gets called indefinite so first remove callback because it may be added already        
            holder.myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
            holder.myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 0);

            //...
     }
```

}

The problem is to remove the callback for a view thats not visible anymore because in getView() I get noticed when a view becomes visible but I have no clue how to get the view (and thereby the holder and it's handler) that became invisible to remove the callback.

Is there a(nother) approach to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a clean solution (if someone needs something like that). I needed to update a TextView to set the new counter value (every second).

In BaseAdapters getView I add the TextViews(s) to a WeakHashMap. The TextView is the key of the map. A key/value mapping will be removed if the key is no longer referenced. So I do not cause memory leaks. The GarbageCollector does the work.

A thread counts "counter objects" down and refreshes the TextViews with the corresponding values (GarbageCollector runs all the time so in my case the map consists mostly of 3 items because the gallery shows just one item. Due to GarbageCollection the map gets immediately cleared by "unused" TextViews specially when scrolling fast through the list/gallery)

BaseAdapter's getView():

```
private WeakHashMap<TextView, Integer> counterMap = new WeakHashMap<TextView,Integer>();
private Handler counterHandler = new Handler();

public View getView(...) {
    //...
    counterMap.put(holder.tvCounter, position);
    //...
}
```

The counter:

```
// Thread decrementing the time of the counter objects and updating the UI
private final Runnable counterTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //...
        // decrement the remaining time of all objects
        for (CounterData data : counterDataList) 
            data.decrementTimeLeftInSeconds();

        // iterate through the map and update the containing TextViews
        for (Map.Entry<TextView, Integer> entry : counterMap.entrySet()) {
            TextView tvCounter = entry.getKey();
            Integer position = entry.getValue();
            CounterData data = counterDataList.get(position);
            long timeLeftInSeconds = data.getTimeLeftInSeconds();
            tvCounter.setText(" " + timeLeftInSeconds);
        }

        if (yourCondition)
            counterHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

Start/stop the counter:

```
public void startCounter() { counterHandler.post(counterTimeTask); }
public void stopCounter() { counterHandler.removeCallbacks(counterTimeTask); }
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' to help others find your solution.  Cheers~